# Sketching histogram from "image table"

Tags: histogram

I've stumbled upon a somewhat easy question, yet it differs from regular histogram drawing:

"Sketch a histogram of the 4-bit image shown below:"

[image: table of image]

I know that histogram is drawn from collecting some data and it's frequency, and then drawing higher waves when higher frequency in the histogram.

I'm guessing this table is supposed to represent an image and the numbers probably the intensity of some color or grey-level... I don't really know how to collect the data and frequency from it, just take each number in particular and how many times it appears?
I know the answer should be simple ^^

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've drawn this into an excel table, is this correct or should it be done in a different way?

The whole "4-bit image" thing confuses me...

[image: my try]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a 4-bit image gray scale values ranges from 0-15.
Apart from 18th (and plus) row(s) of your excel sheet all is good.